# How do I create clean URLs such that what is currently in a parameter goes in the path?

Tags: htaccess, url-rewriting, clean-urls

My url is `http://localhost/store/product-detail.php?p=prod%name%test`
i want it to look like this 
`http://localhost/store/prod-name-test`
or something like this as other stores do `http://localhost/store/p/prod-name-test`

I tried so many codes on .htaccess none of them worked. This is my current code

```
# mod_rewrite starts here 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f

RewriteRule \//product-detail.php\s(.*) http://localhost/store/p/?p=Dress$1 [R=301,L]


#RewriteRule ^users/(\d+)*$ ./product-detail.php?p=$1
#RewriteRule ^?([a-zA-Z0-9=_-]+)$ product-detail.php?$1 [NC,L] 
#Options +FollowSymLinks
#RewriteRule ^/?$ /product-detail.php [QSA,L]
```

I tried also `window.history.pushState("", "", "/p/<?php echo $prod_name; ?>");`.
It doesn't work.

The most important thing is that the link should respect the SEO.  I should also be able to use the request method `?p=` even if its hidden.

Comment: `.htaccess` can't modify the links in your HTML pages.   I'm not sure if that is what you mean by "link should respect the SEO", but if so, you need to find another solution for that part.

Comment: "`?p=prod%name%test`" - You've used unencoded `%` in your _actual_ URL - is this intentional? (So this would also require conversion to `-` in your "desired" URL format?)

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right path by using url rewriting but your rewrite rules can be simplified.

**.htaccess File**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

What this .htaccess file will do is redirect all browser requests which don't match an actual directory or file in your web application to the `index.php` file. From there you can then decode the URL to handle is however you wish.

In this way by using a very simple rewrite rule you can use URL's such as `domain.com/store/category-name/product-name` and return the appropriate data.

A good starting point for a lot of this would be to take a look at any number of PHP application frameworks which include request routing as part of the underlying package.